# Construction Dilemma Holds Both Ways?!!

Tags: propositional-calculus

In page 37 of [A Transition to Advanced Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1285463269), the authors intend to prove a statement of general logical form $P\vee Q\Rightarrow R_{1}\vee R_{2}$ where $P,Q,R_{1},R_{2}$ are predicates, "...The proof method we choose is to show that $P\Rightarrow R_{1}$ and $Q\Rightarrow R_{2}$." I cannot understand how these are equivalent, particularly because of the Constructive Dilemma stated in page 16 of [Set Theory With Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0931541042):
$$
[(P\Rightarrow Q)\wedge(R\Rightarrow S)]\Rightarrow(P\vee R\Rightarrow Q\vee S)
$$
As you can observe, this is a conditional statement and not a biconditional which I interpret as one is not permitted to derive $(P\Rightarrow Q)\wedge (R\Rightarrow S)$ while assumming $(P\vee R\Rightarrow Q\vee S)$ as antecedent at all times. Can anyone explain how their "proof method" is valid?

Comment: They are not ***equivalent***, but if they prove that $P \implies R_1$ and $Q \implies R_2$, then that ***implies*** that $P \vee Q \implies R_1 \vee R_2$, which is what they want to show, right?

Comment: In the statement on p.$37$ of the cited book that $\ [P\vee Q\Rightarrow R]\iff[(P\Rightarrow R)\wedge(Q\Rightarrow R)]\ $ is a tautology, the logical expression should instead be $\ [P\vee Q\Rightarrow R]\Leftarrow[(P\Rightarrow R)\wedge(Q\Rightarrow R)]\ $.  I suspect it's just a misprint.

Comment: The converse of what you say is true [Joe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/693577/joe). But as you have stated, they are not equivalent and you cannot assume the consequent and derive the antecedent.